# langchain\\chains\\llm_summarization_checker\\prompts\\create_facts.txt error when try to package python file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, langchain

I tried to `pyinstaller` package my python file which uses `langchain`. i.e it imports:

```
from langchain.text_splitter import CharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
from langchain.vectorstores import FAISS
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.callbacks import get_openai_callback
```

But when packaging, these imports cause the following error when I try to run the executable.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\chatgpt\\dist\\chat\\langchain\\chains\\llm_summarization_checker\\prompts\\create_facts.txt'
```

[image]

Comment: Same error here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: same issue @serge unfortunately your answer didn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on Win11 and Python 3.10:

1. Create the exe like this:

   pyinstaller --hidden-import=pytorch --collect-data torch --copy-metadata torch --copy-metadata tqdm --copy-metadata regex --copy-metadata requests --copy-metadata packaging --copy-metadata filelock --copy-metadata numpy --copy-metadata tokenizers --hidden-import="sklearn.utils._cython_blas" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors.typedefs" --hidden-import="sklearn.neighbors.quad_tree" --hidden-import="sklearn.tree" --hidden-import="sklearn.tree._utils" myscript.py
2. Copy the langchain folder (located in the packages of the python local install) into the "dist" folder (to get all these txt files). For me the langchain folder was located at: "C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\langchain"

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
pyinstaller --paths ".venv/" --collect-data=langchain --onefile --name "ai_agent" main.py
```

Comment: You're the real MVP.  Easy and correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I was trying with `--onefile` option and it was failing as the current file path will be in `Temp` directory. So, create exe without `--onefile` option. Once done, as suggested by serge copy the `langchain` directory from `site-packages` within `dist\<yourapp>` directory.

In the solution suggested by Serge Step 1 is not necessary.

Comment: Did you get it to work with the `--onefile` option?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `--onefile` mode when you add the langchain folder as additional data. You can add it by adding the following line to the spec file:

`a.datas += Tree('path/to/folder', prefix='langchain')`

Answer (score 0):

I followed all the steps outlined previously, but the resulting executable file is not functioning correctly. When I attempted to debug the executable using --debug=all in PyInstaller, I observed in the command prompt that it is failing to import Langchain modules.

```
community\\vectorstores\\utils.pyc' import 'langchain_community.vectorstores.utils' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x000001F5D30EB450> import 'langchain_community.vectorstores.faiss' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x000001F5D30D73D0> import 'langchain.vectorstores.faiss' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourcelessFileLoader object at 0x000001F5D30C16D0>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I spent a considerable amount of time tackling a specific problem and have found a solution, or rather a workaround, that I'd like to share. This approach is particularly useful for those looking to create an executable from a Python application without using the `--onefile` command. Here's a step-by-step guide:

1. Create a virtual environment and install all the required packages.
2. Instead of using the `--onefile` command, create an executable in the
   usual way.
3. Go to the virtual environment's `Lib/site-packages` folder
   and copy all the installed packages.
4. Paste these packages into the `dist/main/__internal__` folder or the
   equivalent location where your executable stores its packages.

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve issues related to importing Python packages in your executable. This method has certainly worked well in my experience and could be a viable solution for similar problems.